# Fatal Error on Magento 2.3 installation process (localhost/magento)

Tags: magento2.2.3

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Warning: "continue" targeting switch
>   is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\ArrayObject.php
>   on line 426 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, '"continue" targ...',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 426, Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444):
>   include() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322):
>   Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 [internal
>   function]:
>   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Zend\Stdlib\Arr...') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\Parameters.php(29):
>   spl_autoload_call('Zend\Stdlib\Arr...') #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-http\src\PhpEnvironment\Request.php(67):
>   Zend\Stdlib\Parameters->__construct(Array) #6 C:\xamp in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 941

Answer (score 1):

You should try it.

if you have PHP 7.3 then change it with PHP 7.2

And use Magento version 2.3

then start.